# I want compare two string and want to get possible matches

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

`sb.Qualilfication_Master.First().Qual_List`  contain string values like "B.C.A,M.C.A,B.B.A"
and `txtQualification.text` contain string like "B.C.A, M.Com"
I want match above two thing

```
var sendnoti = (from p in db.Reg_JobSeeker_Masters where p.Qualification_Masters.First().Qual_List.Contains(txtQualification.Text)select p).ToList();
```

Comment: Please provide the C# types of the variables in question. Please explain what "I want match above two thing" means in programming terms.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this right - and you want to find the strings that are common to two lists - then you can just use the intersect method.

Answer (score 0):

I am just assuming txtQualification.Text is a `List<string>` so in that case you could just right it like this -

```
var sendnoti = (from p in db.Reg_JobSeeker_Masters where p.Qualification_Masters.First().Qual_List.Any(ql => txtQualification.Text.Contains(ql))select p).ToList();
```